# What will be the best query in mysql for getting a list of employees with their latest time?

Tags: mysql

I've a huge table which makes database hang every time when I need a specific data from it. I want to gather information like latest time of every employees.

Database is like:

```
+----------+-------+----------+
| emp_name | time  | location |
+----------+-------+----------+
| Rama     | 1:05  |   aa     |
| Rama     | 2:10  |   bb     |
| Arju     | 4:30  |   cc     |
| Rama     | 6:00  |   dd     |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

And I need output like:

```
+----------+-------+----------+
| emp_name | time  | location |
+----------+-------+----------+
| Arju     | 4:30  |   cc     |
| Rama     | 6:00  |   dd     |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

I've tried:
1)

```
SELECT emp_name, time, location FROM tbl_emp 
WHERE time IN (SELECT max(time) FROM tbl_emp GROUP BY emp_name);
```

2)

```
SELECT emp_name, time, location FROM tbl_emp AS att 
LEFT JOIN tbl_emp AS tmp ON tmp.emp_name=att.emp_name AND tmp.time>att.time
WHERE tmp.time is NULL 
GROUP BY att.employee_id;
```

But both makes the query too slow.

Comment: SELECT emp_name, max(time)
FROM tbl_emp
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(timeField,'%h.%i%p');

Comment: add ASC , DESC to order in ascending or descending

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar addind ASC or DESC not working with group by

Comment: `order by`, I never said group by.

Comment: Then how will we get only latest time record for all individual employees? @AkshayMulgavkar

Comment: use aggregation on time and group them by emp_name

Answer (score 0):

use group by and aggregation

```
SELECT emp_name, max(time)
FROM tbl_emp
group by emp_name
```

Comment: 01 Jan, 1970 05:30am in every record @fa06

Comment: what is your datatype of time field @RohitGusain

Comment: Ok Sorry! You are right. Probably there is something is missing in my own question. @fa06